# Using websockets in Clojure Ring app deployed to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, clojure, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ring

I'd like to deploy a websocket server to a Tomcat container running on AWS [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) using Ring. I'm not sure how to go about doing that, or if it is even possible without writing a Ring adapter that supports websockets.

I took a look at [ring.util.servlet](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-servlet/src/ring/util/servlet.clj), and it looks like it only handles `HttpServlet`. In order to use websockets with Tomcat, I need to extend `WebSocketServlet`.

I know about [http-kit](http://www.http-kit.org/), which looks really great, but I won't be able to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk, as it can't run in an application container, but must run as a standalone app.

Has anyone deployed a websockets Ring app to Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, http-kit is meant to be used in lieu of Tomcat, [but you can use a reverse proxy like nginx](http://www.http-kit.org/server.html#deploy). If that's something you really don't want to do, you could consider using [Pedestal with SSE instead of websockets](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/guides/documentation/service-sse.md).

Other than that, it doesn't look like there are any ring libs for websocket support, so you'd have to pioneer it yourself.

Comment: I was afraid of that. A reverse proxy wouldn't help me, as I still need to deploy into Elastic Beanstalk. EB now supports Docker, so it may be that the best way forward is to run my http-kit app in a Docker container.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at [vertx](http://vertx.io/) which has built in support for websockets. There is a clojure language support. [see here.](http://vertx.io/core_manual_clojure.html). There is a ring adapter [here](https://github.com/stream1984/ring-vertx-adapter). You could also read about how to embed vertx in your clojure ring based application.

If you are free to use something else besides tomcat, you can try [immutant](http://immutant.org/) which is based on jboss. [Here is an article on immutant, vertx and websockets.](http://immutant.org/news/2013/09/17/websocket-sockjs/)

Josh

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I need something that works on Tomcat. If I don't get a positive answer, I'll have to consider other options.